# Content Porter - issues with import caused by corrupted export package - Blueprint items are incorrect

Tags: 2011-sp1, content-porter-2009

We're midway through a port of content from our production CME back to dev, and are encountering some "bizarre" issues with Content Porter.  The export process had been working OK, but now on the import we are experiencing unexpected behaviour whereby the root Structure Group is localized (incorrectly), renamed to what should be one of its children and then the import of course fails because the WebDav URLs are all incorrect.

We are also experiencing errors like the below when importing a Page:

> (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)
>   (Cause=true)  Unexpected root element: Page. Expected: StructureGroup.
>   (Cause=false)  Unable to update Structure Group (tcm:298-23-4).

I've tried the export with various settings (typically we would exclude Configuration, Default Items and Workflow but have also tried excluding Structure), but the errors remain.

Inspecting the package that Content Porter generates reveals some "interesting" anomalies.  We have, for example, a Structure Group (path /webdav/site/Home/[020] Products) with XML:

```xml
<tcccp:BlueprintParentUrl>/webdav/000%20Empty%20Parent/Home</tcccp:BlueprintParentUrl
<tcccp:PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>/webdav/000%20Empty%20Parent/Home</tcccp:PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>
```

However, this SG is only present in 400 Website Master and localized in the export publication.

**I can change these values, reimport the package and resolve the "localize and rename the root Structure Group" issue.  The child items then import correctly.**

The quoted error when importing a Page seems to be caused similarly.  Again, the XML generated by Content Porter seems to be incorrect:

```xml
<tcccp:BlueprintParentUrl>/webdav/000%20Empty%20Parent/Home</tcccp:BlueprintParentUrl
<tcccp:PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>/webdav/000%20Empty%20Parent/Home</tcccp:PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>
```

This is for a Page which has been localized in a localized Structure Group in the export publication, but (1) has a different Blueprint path (.../Home/[030] Knowledge) and (2) is clearly not a Structure Group.

We have similar issues for Structure Groups that are stating that the Blueprint Parent is a Page in a completely different SG.

I have tried multiple exports and cannot figure out what is causing this.  All previous exports and imports have been successful, and I'm starting to get to the stage where I think I'm going to have to write a Core Service utility to do this.

Tridion version is 2011SP1 and running Content Porter 2009 SP2 (as supplied).    The same version is used in both environments.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before, and how did you resolve it?

Comment: I wonder whether anyone else is doing it this way. It's more usual to bring database restores back through the DTAP, and only to use Content Porter going /towards/ production. (Obviously then you still have some fix-ups to do.) So it may well be that you are the only one seeing this behaviour.

Comment: DB restore is the way we do if needed. CP is tricky if the Publications and item names do not exactly match between the environments. You can also try importing one-by-one item in sequence i.e. starting from schema, templates and then content/pages